# Works in Playground but not in Viewcontroller

Tags: swift

ok, probably very basic:

In playgound this works fine :

```
let userNb:Int = 1229
let testRange = 2..<userNb
```

but when I transfer to xcode with UI button an therefore converting to Int I get "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

```
let testRange = 2 ..< Int(userNb.text!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Int(userNb.text!)` returns an `Int?`. You are basically trying to apply `..<` on an `Int` operand and an `Int?` operand.

There are multiple overloads of `..<` and because you have a `Int?` the compiler can't figure out which overload to use, so it says that it "needs more context".

To fix this, just make sure the optional is unwrapped in some way or another. For example:

```
2..<(Int(userNb.text!) ?? 10)
// or
2..<Int(userNb.text!)!
// or
if let upperBound = Int(userNb.text!) {
    let range = 2..<upperBound
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfect ! I used the last suggestion which is an optional structure if I understand well.
I still don't understand exactly why swift interprets it that way but maybe another day :)

Comment: @DevNoob If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!